# How to access base class Properties Correctly in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Can anyone here please tell me if the below is the right way to inherit a class from the base class.

Thanks.

```
// BaseController.h
@interface BaseController: UIViewController
{
  IBOutlet UITextField* m_pNameTxtFld;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* m_pNameTxtFld;
```

// BaseController.m

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
   if (self.m_pNameTxtFld)
   {
     self.m_pNameTxtFld = nil;
   }
}
```

// NewContorller.h

```
@interface NewContorller: BaseController
{
}
```

// NewContorller.m

```
@implementation NewContorller
```

- (void)viewDidLoad

```
{
  self.m_pNameTxtFld.text = @"Test";
}
```

Comment: Did we hear a trace of a C++ accent here? :-) Your "base class" is also known as a "superclass" and instance variables are not "members", so you don't see the "m_" naming convention much. Just as a heads-up.

Comment: Thanks Monolo...will keep a check on it...:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is the right way. Just remember that you should call [super viewDidLoad] at the beggining of viewDidLoad implementation in subclass.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.m_pNameTxtFld.text = @"Test";
}
```